# Batch to move and rename file (unknown source)

Tags: batch-file, rename, move

I have made a batch script to move and rename a file by dragging and dropping a file onto the script. This will assume the source of the file is unknown, but the target directory is.

My solution was to CD to the target directory, reverse the source file name, use the for command with backslash as a delim to have the file name, then reverse it again then finally rename it.

Just wondering if there was an easier solution.

```
@echo off

echo %1
set newSong=%1

cd "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.0.230\deploy\assets\sounds\ambient"

if not exist LoginScreenIntro.mp3.bak rename LoginScreenIntro.mp3 LoginScreenIntro.mp3.bak
del LoginScreenIntro.mp3

copy %newSong% "%CD%"

Call :ReverseString %newSong%
Set ReverseString.Result="%ReverseString.Result%"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=\" %%a in (%ReverseString.Result%) do set reversesong=%%a
Call :ReverseString "%reversesong%"
set newSong=%ReverseString.Result%

rename "%newSong%" LoginScreenIntro.mp3
pause


:ReverseString
  Set ReverseString.TempVar=%~1
  Set ReverseString.Result=
  :ReverseString.Loop
    Set ReverseString.Result=%ReverseString.TempVar:~0,1%%ReverseString.Result%
    Set ReverseString.TempVar=%ReverseString.TempVar:~1,999%
    if not "%ReverseString.TempVar%"=="" goto ReverseString.Loop
Goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
ren %1 NewName.ext
move %~dp1\NewName.ext NewDir
```

Comment: When you drag and drop a file onto a batch script, the full path and directory are included in the variable. I would like these items stripped... and I think I know how now...

Answer (score 0):

Heh, all I needed was

```
set newsong=%~n1%~x1
```

Comment: Actually, you could just use `%~nx1` :)

Comment: Didn't know batch variable flags are C-like!